# Filter a high volume database and then sending a mass email to those

Tags: php, mysql, apache, sendmail

I have a database with 20k people in it. How can I safely filter through it and then sending an email to those that correspond to my criteria? Let's say my filter returns 5k emails

I was thinking to add a parameter to database; let's say `status` and update it to 1, and then to rewrite the .htaccess to create a cron job that runs a script only for those that have `status` set to 1 from 10 to 10 mins with limit 100 and update `status` to 0 again. Any of you have a better idea? or is my idea bad?

I'm using PHPmailer.

Comment: Why are you setting a parameter 'status' and using limit 100? for sending mails through cron job. Explain me.

Comment: well can't apache or php kill the process if run time of the script is to high?

Comment: An `.htaccess` file will not normally affect a cron job. Are you using `wget` and calling the script in a web/Apache context?

Comment: In corn job the their is no script execution time limit, so record count limit is not required. I too worked on the similar task of sending bulk mails.

Comment: well the script that cron runs is a php file and since i'm using a shard hosing i have 30sec